# New Branch in TFS 2015 merges completely in Baseless merge

Tags: version-control, tfs-2015, powerbuilder

Setting up new projects and branch designs in TFS 2015. This detail may be significant - I'm using it for PowerBuilder projects, not .NET - VS2015 is used to set up branches and perform merges, the files themselves will be checked in and out in PowerBuilder. Far as I can see that shouldn't make a difference, but mentioning it in case I've missed something

Using the following sample layout:

[image]

Prod branches to/from  Mod, down to Dev. New CO projects branch from Prod (so they always start with a fresh set of the latest live code), then merged (via baseless merge) to the DEV branch, and re-parented once the connection is set up. That way the users wouldn't have to remember to do a baseless merge; Dev will become the default merge target

Merges would them go back up from Dev to Mod, then back to Prod

The issue is that as a test, I tried the baseless merge after the branch, expecting no files to be merged, as nothing has changed yet in any branch. But the merge from the CO branch to Dev merged ALL files. Not an issue now since there's no changes in place, but would be quite a problem once several projects have been merged to DEV.

After that merge, I made a small change in the project and tried a merge; only the one changed file merged.

My best guess is that since the new CO branch was created after the Dev Branch, it was seen as everything in it is newer than the Dev branch, so it rolled over everything.  Not sure how it would treat changes in Dev not seen in the Prod branch yet, haven't tested that scenario.  It SHOULD at the very least tell me there's changes that I need to merge, but I fear it might just roll over them with the "new" files in the CO branch.

The question is, how can/do I tell the system that this new branch is "not newer" than the Dev branch? Does indeed the fact that these are PowerBuilder files somehow limit the ability of TFS of recognizing versioning in some way?

Or even more simply, is the branch layout I'm trying not the best method?

EDIT - here's the structure I'm currently using for my .NET projects - I was trying to use the layout above instead for the new code.

[image]

It uses the "Main" branch suggested below in the comments, but since I'm pulling "CO Branches" from Dev, I get code currently being tested, and not pristine Prod code. I'm assuming trying to branch and re-parent from Prod in this layout would result in the same scenario.

So is this the better way to go after all?

Comment: Baseless merges are without history so you will likely get significant regressions as you overwrite things in Dev.

Comment: I was under the impression this would be the best way to set the structure up to ensure I got fresh, current code for new changes. Better suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Why do you need MOD and Dev at all? Why not just use MAIN/TRUNK/MASTER and always have working code.

Comment: As someone who has used PowerBuilder within TFS for many years all I can say is the safest way to 'merge' code is to manually code in every branch you want the modification in.  So in your example if you want a change in C0002 to go to PROD you code in PB for DEV, MOD, and PROD. If you only have one developer working in the code at any give time you probably can merge.

Comment: @MrHinsh - we maintain three servers - Development, Model Office and Production, and different teams test on each. As you can see from the diagram, we have multiple jobs running, merging and testing at any one time, to the code bases for each can vary. Suggestions for alternate branch design to serve those needs are welcome.

Comment: @MattBalent - Alas, we have multiple developers in the code, which is why this more complex design is the desired option. As mentioned just above, different code at varying points in the process requires (or seems to) this multi-step process.

Comment: Work with teams that have 100's of developers and only one branch. You need to move away from branch promotion and towards binary promotion.

Comment: I found an article by you on nkdagility that also talks about this process, but no details about it. Suggested links for a tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a Main branch, which is the junction branch between development and release branches, representing a stable snapshot of the product.

You can branch from Main to Dev, Mod and Prod, when the work on Dev branch finished, merge from Dev to Main, when you want to release the product, merge from Main to Prod. So when you want to branch from the latest live code, you can branch from Main. In this way, you can merge from CO to Main, then Main to Dev or Main to Prod. All changesets will be reserved.

Comment: Actually I use the "Main Branch" design currently, and I was trying to move away from it, as I thought pulling from Prod was better.  I've updated the question with a diagram of that layout, in the hopes it will be useful. Perhaps it's not quite the layout you're thinking of

Comment: You can branch from Main to Dev, Mod and Prod, and merge back from Dev, Mod and Prod to Main, then when you want to branch from the latest live code, you can branch from Main. In this way, you can merge from CO to Main, then Main to Dev or Main to Prod. No need to re-parent CO branches.